# Vaadin cannot be used in cloud without sticky-session?

Tags: amazon-web-services, session, cloud, vaadin

In the last four years we have been using Vaadin (currently 8 and 14) for different products generating a 7-digit revenue and are generally happy with it. Now my colleagues tell me they want to switch to alternative frameworks because Vaadin cannot be used in the cloud without sticky sessions. They have tried redis and Hazlecast. Our devops simply refuse to give us sticky sessions. Is this where we have to say goodbye to Vaadin or do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Relatively heavy server-side state is the price that you pay for the developer convenience that Vaadin provides. It's an architectural trade-off without any easy workarounds.

One alternative is Vaadin Fusion (available with Vaadin 15 and newer) which is based on stateless endpoints and instead managing the UI state in TypeScript that runs in the browser. It's a somewhat different flavour of Vaadin compared to what you're used to with Vaadin 8 or Vaadin 14, but it's still the same Vaadin components and the same end-to-end integration of the whole stack.